# Google Calendar API quota per project or per key?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Google document [Google Calendar API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing) states 1M queries per day. Is the quota per project or per service account/client? I know it is possible to request increase of quota, but want to know if multiple service accounts can each have 1M queries per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most Quotas are project based.  So if you have a single project on google developer console and you create six service accounts they will all be using the same quota.

If you create two projects on google developer console and create a service account on each then they will each have their own quota.

You may still want to apply for the extension it doesn't cost anything but it can take a while to get approved.